# jQuery - on hover leave keep div visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the question title, I really didn't know how to summarise it a short description.

Essentially I have got a `<ul>` which has my navigation links. However in one of the `<li>` links is my custom dropdown shopping basket to give the user a preview of their items.

Now when I hover over the element , I want it to change the basket from `display:none` to `display:block` making it visible. But with my code, as soon as I leave the hovered element to click on an item. The dropdown disappears because I'm no longer hovering over the element I defined in my jQuery hover function.

For example (quick dummy code)

```
$('.hover-on-me').hover(function(){
    $('.hover-open').show();
},function(){
//This right here hides the dropdown
    $('.hover-open').hide();
});
```

Now I'm not the bets at javascript/jQuery. I have tried to say in the function, if the mouse is still on the navigation bar , don't hide it or if the mouse is on the shopping basket then don't hide it. I thought this would let me move from the hover element, past the navigation bar and onto the drop down menu but it doesn't work. as the element then stays open and doesn't close when i leave the area.

[Here is a simple jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on9wtk2b/6/) demonstrating my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: use toggle() instead show/hide

Comment: [a non-javascript way to do this](https://jsfiddle.net/on9wtk2b/11/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mistake in your class name only.

jQuery Code :-

```
$('.hover-on-me').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
}, function(){
    $(this).parent("li").removeClass("active");
});
```

Add this to you CSS Code :-

```
ul li.active{display:inline-block;}
ul li.active .hover-open, ul li .hover-open:hover{display:block;}
```

Can you please try these.

Comment: sorry , i put the wrong code in. I have edited my question with correct link now. You will see then when you try to hover on .hover-open it closes

Comment: @virepo Can you please try my answer?

Comment: I will explain you if you have any issue with that.

Comment: I have one more option if you have any issue with the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

the hover syntax will look like this.. **$(selector).hover(inFunction,outFunction)** 
and try to modify your script like this..

```
$('.hover-on-me').hover(
function(){
$('.hover-open').show();
},
function(){
if(!$('ul').is(":hover") || !$('.hover-open').is(":hover")){
    $('.hover-open').hide();
}
}
);
```

OR 
use mouse event function..

```
$( ".hover-on-me" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
   $('.hover-open').show();
 });

$( ".hover-open" )
.mouseleave(function() {
$('.hover-open').hide();
});
```

for further details refer here..https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2 and https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: that's the exact code in my question just formatted different?

Comment: actually it doesnt, i cannot get my mouse to hover over .hover-open before it closes